# How to Ajax search by full name if first name and last name is in different columns?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search

I am open for any ideas or solutions, I wanted to search data from the database by full name but first name and last name is in different columns inside the table.

For example i search Zakir Raza,

In database:

firstname - Zakir

lastname - Raza

Thanks!

```
<
? php
//connecting database
include_once 'connect.php';

//creating veriables
$search_value = $_POST["search"];
$serchin = $_POST["search"];
$searcharry = str_split($serchin);

// print_r($searcharry);

//creating sql function
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE firstName LIKE '%{$search_value}%' OR lastName LIKE '%{$search_value}%' OR mobile LIKE '%{$search_value}%' OR address LIKE '%{$search_value}%'";

?
>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you're facing? Your code seems good, apart from the fact that if you want the full name you need to change from `OR` to `AND.

Comment: use (I mean add) `or concat(firstName, ' ' , lastname) like '%{$search_value}%'`

Comment: Thanks it working now. i have used this code " or concat(firstName, ' ' , lastname) like '%{$search_value}%' "